# How to download external data such as json for use by ios

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have built a web app in php (beginner programmer) which displays local json data in table format and am now wanting to recreate the functionality in iOS.

For my web app I use a shell script run from my webserver to CURL the remote data from an API and store 'locally' (in my root folder on my web server), and then access and parse from there using php.

I am trying to work out how to do this for iOS (at a basic level, not worrying about caching for offline use at this stage).

1. What are the means (I assume classes and methods, I am new to OOP) within iOS to get (using http GET) external data and store it locally?
2. Where is the usual place to store it?

Much searching hasn't helped, partly due to my newness with Swift and OOP. I think I just need a starting place for my iOS learning journey and am hoping that some high level signposts and perhaps even methods and classes to search for will help me go on and get my hands dirty.

Comment: Check out AFNetworking.   Here is a tutorial for Swift: http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial

Comment: As a beginner I would not use AFNetworking or any other 3rd party library to such basic stuff as fetching a JSON. Look up `NSURLSession` in the documentation. It's easier that AFNetworking and you have the chance to understand what you are doing.

Comment: NSURLSession - I've had a look and that is perfect. Don't know how to indicate this is the answer as it was just a comment.